# Continuity of piecewise infinite series function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\ee}{ \varepsilon }$
Let $\{q_k\}_k=(-1,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Define functions $f_k, f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$f_k(t) = \cases{(t-q_k)^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{t-q_k}\right) & if $t\ne q_k$,\\
0 & if $t=q_k$}$$

$$f(t) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}f_k(t).$$

I want to show that $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$.

> Solution:

$$f_k'(t) = \begin{cases}2(t-q_k)\sin\left(\frac{1}{t-q_k}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{t-q_k}\right), & \text{ if } t\ne q_k\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Thus $f'(t)=\sum_k \frac{1}{2^k}f'_k(t)$. Also, $|f_k'(t)|\le 2\cdot 2\cdot 1+1=5$. Thus $$\left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} \right|=|f_k'(c)|\le 5,$$
where $c\in (t,s)$. Now,

$$\left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} -\sum_k \frac{1}{2^k} f_k'(t) \right| \le \sum_k \frac{1}{2^k} \left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} - f_k'(t) \right|$$
$$\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} - f_k'(t) \right| + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} - f_k'(t) \right|$$
$$<\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} - f_k'(t) \right| + \ee,$$

where we take $k\ge K\in\mathbb N$, such that $n\ge K$ implies $\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} - f_k'(t) \right|<\ee$.

But that's where I'm stuck. I'd appreciate if someone could please help me with finishing my proof.

Also, as far as I understand, the points of discontinuity of $f'$ are $q_k$. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm too unfamiliar with derivatives of infinite sums, but to me it sounds like you're overcomplicating things. You have $|f'_k(t)| \leq 5$, which means $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} f'_k(t)$ always converges.

Comment: @orlp Right, but how do I finish the inequality? Should it be $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \left| \frac{f_k(t)-f_k(s)}{t-s} - f_k'(t) \right|< \epsilon$ for $|t-s|<\delta$?

Comment: I don't believe I ever mentioned an inequality.